# What could be causing the 'unavailable' error when trying to add a filter to my Salesforce dashboard on Opportunity Owner field?

Tags: salesforce, report, dashboard, sfdc

I want to put the filter on the dashboard level of Salesforce on field of 'opportunity owner role'.
The report on the dashboard are made up of different report types but most of the reports are made up of opportunity report type.

When I put filter on dashboard level on opportunity owner field then I am getting error on dashboard that "The component can't be displayed because the field(s) you chose for the filter are unavailable." on some of the component

I have checked all the report type and they have 'opportunity owner role' file on the every report type field layout and they are also showing up on the report builder and can be added as the column in the report.